# UI spinner bug when changing value using mouse up and down

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I added the decimal spinner to my site.

My value was 56.20. 
When I change use mouse wheel up, I am expecting 57.20, but now it is showing 57:00.

The function is shown below:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#spinner" ).spinner({
      step: 1.00,
      numberFormat: "n"
    });

    $( "#culture" ).change(function() {
      var current = $( "#spinner" ).spinner( "value" );
      Globalize.culture( $(this).val() );
      $( "#spinner" ).spinner( "value", current );
    });
  });
  </script>
```

I had included the the [demo too](http://plnkr.co/edit/oa94gjFhGTDzFKtEXI9W?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug at all sorry to say, it's simply rounding up - I think this the part in the jQuery code within the [spinner.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.spinner.js#L324) that actions the round up:

During the `_spin()`:

```
value = this._adjustValue( value + step * this._increment( this.counter ) );
```

Calls `_adjustValue()`:

```
_adjustValue: function( value ) {
    var base, aboveMin,
        options = this.options;

    // make sure we're at a valid step
    // - find out where we are relative to the base (min or 0)
    base = options.min !== null ? options.min : 0;
    aboveMin = value - base;

    // - round to the nearest step
    aboveMin = Math.round(aboveMin / options.step) * options.step;

    // - rounding is based on 0, so adjust back to our base
    value = base + aboveMin;

    // fix precision from bad JS floating point math
    value = parseFloat( value.toFixed( this._precision() ) );

    // clamp the value
    if ( options.max !== null && value > options.max) {
        return options.max;
    }
    if ( options.min !== null && value < options.min ) {
        return options.min;
    }

    return value;
},
```

**Source**: [jQuery UI GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.spinner.js#L324)

But what you could try, is catching the value before spinning & then re-adjusting the value after a completed spin, based on what you had before with the two callback events below:

```
var beforeSpin = 1.00;

$( "#spinner" ).spinner({
      step: 1.10,
      numberFormat: "n",
      start: function( event, ui ) {
          beforeSpin = ui.value;
      },
      //or stop: function(){}
      spin: function( event, ui ) {
          //Do some re-value
          //funciton based on old value
      }
});
```

That, or re-program the `_adjustValue: function()` to your needs - Open source after all :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good here, just set your step to 1.10.

Example:

```
$( "#spinner" ).spinner({
  step: 1.10,
  numberFormat: "n"
});
```

Peep the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/FyyAYSgEmVdb8NHbdZBz?p=preview)

I should add that you can adjust the increment value accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't work properly, as it will step by `1` only on the first click, but then by `1.1` on successive clicks, thereby ruining the effect.

Comment: @D.Alexander Thanks for the reply. but the still the problem is not solved. I want 1.00 as difference.