# Jquery spinner adds min value after spinning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Configuring a spinner like this

```
 $( "#spinner" ).spinner({   
  step: 1.,    
  min: 0.01,    
  max: 10.0,    
  numberFormat: "n",      
});
```

leads to a unwanted behavior:

when using a start value .i. from 1 spinning up sets the value to 2.01 instead of 2. I tied several ways to fix this like i.e. described here:
[UI spinner bug when changing value using mouse up and down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063956/ui-spinner-bug-when-changing-value-using-mouse-up-and-down)

But i find no way to get rid of this behavior. When stepping up the number should increase by exactly 1 and not less or more as long as min and max are not violated.
Any ways to work around this?

Comment: Take out all the decimal places and you'll get whole numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem here is?  Min value = 0.01 + 1 = 1.01.  1.01+1 = 2.01.   If you want "+1" to "=2" then it needs to start at "1" (or start at "0").   "*When stepping up the number should increase by exactly 1*" - 0.01 + 1 = 1.01 **so increases by exactly 1**

Comment: @freedomn-m I disagree. No user wants to spin numbers from 1 to 2.01 or the like. The value must not be 0. It may be smaller than 1 but but usually it will be a integer. So if the current value is 1 and i spin one up - it should become 2 - thats what every user expects.

Comment: So your issue is that `1+1=2.01` ?  Can you provide a snippet that demonstrates this?

Comment: From your link and https://jqueryui.com/spinner/#default looks like it's by design.  They *expect* your min value to align with your step value (eg min 1, step 0.1) - in your case it doesn't so the spinner compensates - eg min 1, step 1, value 1.5 -> spin -> 3 not 2.5 as 2.5 doesn't fit in the min+steps alignment.

Comment: Did you try the solution in the link you provided?  (overwrite the adjustment)

Comment: @freedomn-m Heres a sample: https://jsfiddle.net/hcfqxno7/6/#&togetherjs=Qf1sSfh0ik

Comment: "Did you try the solution in the link you provided? (overwrite the adjustment) " Yes i tried that in a number of ways.